# Improve loading speed withouth loosing search ranking

Tags: seo, template-engine, google-crawlers

I have a webpage whit many areas whose visibility can get toggled by the user.
The default visibility state for those area is hidden (css, display: none).
I don't have control to what's going to be put inside, but it could be a lot of images.

I saw with firefox's network observer all images where loaded with the page. This is quite a waste of bandwidth since the user might choose not to display every areas.

I came to a workarround, I put all that content inside a `<script type="late-rendering"></script>` and to avoid any potential conflict (eg: "" inside the content), I replace all "<" with "8691jQfdtxm" (randomly picked string). Then when the user want to make an area visible, I just fill the area with that content after replacing 8691jQfdtxm with "<".

It works fine, but I think proceeding like this will make crawlers (eg: Google) think my webpage is pure garbage. How could I avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

Unless search engines were heavily relying on the `alt` tags of your images, or their `filenames`, there is little risk you will loose search rankings. If your site does load more quickly instead, it will provide a better user experience, which will be probably detected by Google, and this influences rankings positively.

Answer (score 0):

Google executes a lot of Javascript these days. And your trick of breaking the html with a random string seems hokey to me.

I would preload all the textual content ( e.g. have it all in there on first load, with the div closed via display:none ). This content will not count as much as visible content - but it does count.

Then I'd do a delayed loading of the images. Like with make all your images something like:

```
<img src="blank.jpg" loadlater="realimage.jpg">
```

blank.jpg can be a tiny image. when the div opens you can use javascript/jquery to rewrite each src with loadlater.